# HttpResponseRedirect in inclusion tag

Tags: django

I have made an inclusion tag for login form, that will be displayed in every page.
But I am unable to redirect the page after successful login.

Here is my code:

```
from django import template
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.http.response import HttpResponseRedirect

register = template.Library()

def costumlogin(context):
    request = context['request']
    if request.user.is_anonymous():
        state = "Please log in below..."
        username = password = ''
        if 'mylogin' in request.POST:
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            password = request.POST.get('password')

            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    state = "You're successfully logged in!"
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER','/'))
                else:
                   state = "Your account is not active, please contact the site admin."
           else:
                state = "Your username and/or password were incorrect."
        return {'username':username, "state": state}

register.inclusion_tag('registration/login.html',takes_context = True)(costumlogin)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this, it makes no sense. Only a view can return a response, including a redirect.

A template tag is not the appropriate place to process a form. You should get the form to post to a different URL and do the processing in that view.